# Db2 performance - many batch programs inserting rows in the same table

Tags: db2

Hi there I'm looking for advice from someone who is good at IBM db2 performance.

I have a situation in which many batch tasks are massively inserting rows in the same db2 table, at the same time.

This situation looks potentially bad. I don't think db2 is able to resolve the many requests quickly enough, causing the concurring tasks to take longer to end and even causing some of them to abend with a -904 or -911 sqlcode.

What do you guys think? Should situations like these be avoided? Are there some sort of techniques that could improve the performance of the batch tasks, keeping them from abending or running too slow?

Thanks.

Comment: There are number of ways one can try to improve `INSERT` performance, most important were included here as answers already (`APPEND ON`, changes in indexes), few others, like batching the inserts etc. can be found here:
https://developer.ibm.com/articles/dm-0403wilkins/
It is impossible to say what kind of bottleneck you are hitting. If you can easily reproduce the insert slowness please collect db2mon:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21993956
during the issue and post the report here - it should allow me to tell where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting should not be a big problem running ETL workloads i.e. with DataStage do this all the time. 
I suggest to run an

```
ALTER TABLE <tabname> APPEND ON
```

This avoids the free space search - details can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0009677.html)

With the errors reported the information provided is not sufficient to get the cause of it.

Comment: thank you very much. this "append on" mode looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider. What indexes are on the table is one.

Append mode works well to relieve last page contention, there are also issues where you could see contention with the statement itself for the variation lock. Then you could have issues with the transaction logs if they are not fast enough.

What is the table, indexes and statement and maybe we can come up with how to do it. What hardware are you using and what io subsystem is being used for transaction logs and database tablespaces.

Comment: is is a table that is used only to store records written by batch tasks is ZOS. the potential problem that I am foreseeing is that, as more jobs execute simultaneously, the bigger the chances of having an abend due to contention. it happened some few times already.

Comment: You should ask this question in db2-zos.